# how to create photo gallery from the pics using throughout in app

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ios6

how to create photo gallery within the app from the 70 pics using throughout in app

```
ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2a.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2b.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2c.png"],
                             nil];
```

Do i have to create uiimagepicker like this

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

If yes then still not clear that how it will collect all the images from throughout the app and show it as a slide show or the user can slide image one by one.

Thanks for help.

Comment: UIImagePickerController shows the photos stored in the user's "Saved Photo's Album", "Camera Roll" or to use th "Camera" for taking a new photo. If you need to display photos in the bundle, stored in the array, you'll need to roll your own implementation here, (Examples: UIScrollView, UIPickerView).

Comment: with uiscrollview can user do zooming on image and sliding to next image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create some photo gallery apps, check out this open source [sample](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser).

Created by Michael Waterfall, which includes photo gallery from images stored on server or locally.

If you want to implement like side show, just slide the scrollView programmatically with some delay or using your own animatons.

Comment: i want to create photo gallery as a button on toolbar within the same app in which i've already used 70 pics. When user will hit the button it will display all the images as photo gallery used from the app.